# Tag synonym request: ([twitter-integration] [twitter-feeds]) -> [twitter]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta, synonym-request

- [twitter-integration](/questions/tagged/twitter-integration) - 9 questions, no wiki
- [twitter-feeds](/questions/tagged/twitter-feeds) - 6 questions, no wiki
- [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter) - 36 questions, wiki excerpt:

  > Questions and suggestions about Twitter integration.

Would it make sense to merge [twitter-integration](/questions/tagged/twitter-integration) and [twitter-feeds](/questions/tagged/twitter-feeds) into [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. [twitter-integration](/questions/tagged/twitter-integration) and [twitter-feeds](/questions/tagged/twitter-feeds) are now merged and synonymized with [twitter](/questions/tagged/twitter).