# How to handle unanswered tag-merge/retag requests

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Now, there are quite a few posts from users who want [attention/answers for old unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).  The answer to the original and most popular question on the subject is twofold: either update your question with the progress you've made toward solving the problem, or offer a bounty.

This is great advice for handling questions on SO, but I don't think it applies as well on meta (or at least not where tag-merge etc. requests are concerned).  If I think a pair of tags ought to be merged, or burninated, or whatever else, my first course of action will be of course to check meta to see if there's already a question posted concerning this.  Today I stumbled across [this merge request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115987/tag-synonym-request-twitter-integration-twitter-feeds-twitter?rq=1) from December 2011, which has no answers, no upvotes, no comments...  No attention whatsoever.  So I direct myself to the two presented solutions: update the question with my progress or offer a bounty.

1. Update the question with my progress, does not in any way apply.  It's not my question, and there's no progress to be made; I'm not trying to solve a problem, I'm agreeing with a tag merge request.  There's nothing valuable I can edit into the post to garner more attention.
2. Offer a bounty.  I'm going to be honest here, I'm really not likely to do that.  That's a minimum of 50 of my own rep I have to offer to get attention for a tag merge request, with no guarantee whatsoever a solution will actually be reached.  If it was a question that needed something other than essentially a yes-or-no answer, I'd be willing to invest in the bounty system.  In this case?  Not really.

So what are some steps that can be taken in situations like this?  Duplicate questions are obviously bad, but at the same time I haven't seen a realistic solution presented to gain attention to questions like these.  How can we reintroduce the topic of tag merge/burninate/etc requests that were simply missed at the time without posting duplicate questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to diamond mods having uber diamond mod powers, they can field retag or tag merge requests much easier, especially compared to a <10K user. Given this, I would **upvote**, and **flag** the original question for moderator attention. Choose *other*, and mention that the request should be reviewed by a mod.

Couple of good outcomes can come of this:

1. The mod says **yay** to the request, and either actions it themselves or provides their approval for any 10K+ or other users to action the request. This will both a) bump the retag to the front page, where meta users will see it and hopefully help out, and b) give you some incentive to offer a bounty since you know the request should be fielded but you aren't in a position to do so yourself (could be because mass retagging for <10K users is quite inefficient).
2. The mod says **nay** and explains why those tags are useful as they currently are. You've still accomplished your mission to draw attention to the question.

Comment: This would definitely get the requests attention--thank you for your response! Two thoughts: 1) Is it acceptable to flag for this reason? 2) If so... If the moderator decides the merge request is not a good idea, won't they decline the flag and hurt the flagger's flag weight?

Comment: 1) Robert Harvey mentions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136805/whats-the-etiquette-for-retag-requests-and-synonym-requests) that a moderator is often the one to process the request. This means it's definitely worth drawing to their attention one which was missed, but is still valid. 2) The flag will be deemed helpful as it drew attention to the question for the right reason (a decision needed to be made on the retag request).

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's an excellent post of yours that darvids linked to :) Can you confirm that flagging is appropriate in these cases? darvids, thank you very much for your response, I appreciate it. I'd like to keep the bounty open for a few more days in hopes of gathering ideas, but I will award it to you if other answers do not come along. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: (note that since Robert hasn't participated in this question, you can't ping him with an `@username`)

Comment: I can confirm that I used this method successfully, Anna Lear handled the flag and processed my request :)  Thanks for your answer!